# Booting time more than 90 sec

Tags: boot

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 from the last few days, but the loading time to get to the lock screen is more than 60-90 seconds.
I tried many methods mentioned in this forum but got no good result

I don't know much about Ubuntu, so please help me to boot it fast.

Startup Manager: Only "im-Launch" and "SSH Key Agent" is enabled

**systemd-analyze**:

```
Startup finished in 6.114s (firmware) + 5.232s (loader) + 4.859s (kernel) + 1min 8.433s (userspace) = 1min 24.640s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 8.274s in userspace
```

**systemd-analyze blame**:

```
31.577s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
19.551s dev-sda2.device                                      
18.251s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
15.562s snapd.service                                        
14.846s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
10.244s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
 9.084s accounts-daemon.service                              
 8.530s udisks2.service                                      
 8.429s NetworkManager.service                               
 8.308s dev-loop1.device                                     
 7.360s dev-loop11.device                                    
 7.340s dev-loop8.device                                     
 7.340s dev-loop10.device
```

Most time-consuming services. How can I make the boot faster?

Device: Acer Aspire Ryzen 5 2500U vega 8
8GB RAM, 1 TB HDD, 64 bits

Comment: This summer, I diagnosed an overly long boot time being due to the root folder not being owned by root. Chances are slim it is also the case here, but check nevertheless.